# combo box and xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a combo box set inside a xslt using the following code

```
<select name="combo">

            <xsl:for-each select="ConfId">
            </xsl:for-each>

          </select>
```

I wish the combo box to load all the values in the field ConfId of the XML file. Is the above lines of code correct? I am not able to get the combo box to display the details.

Comment: No, the provided code *isn't* correct. It doesn't generate any elements inside the `select` element. And you completely failed to provide the source XML document, so abour *what* "field ConfId" are you talking???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but try this

```
<select name="demo">
 <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node">
  <option>
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
     <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="./@nodeName"/>
  </option>
 </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```